# Resize RGB Tensor pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, interpolation, tensor

I want to resize a 3-D RBG tensor in pytorch. I know how to resize a 4-D tensor, but unfortunalty this method does not work for 3-D.

The input is:

```
#input shape: [3, 100, 200]   ---> desired output shape: [3, 80, 120]
```

if I have a 4-D vector it works fine.

```
#input shape: [2, 3, 100, 200]
out = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(T,size=(100,80), mode='bilinear')
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: just .unsqueeze(0) the input and .squeeze(0) the output. All the torch.nn functions assume dim 0 is the batch dimension. Adding a unitary dimension for dim 0 just makes the functions opperate on a batch size of 1.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to jodag I found the answer:

```
# input shape [3, 200, 120]
T = T.unsqueeze(0)
T = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(T,size=(100,80), mode='bilinear')
T = T.squeeze(0)
# output shape [3, 100, 80]
```